# How to calculate sums of previous rows in a dataframe on rstudio

Tags: r, cumulative-sum

I have a list of dataframes that look like this:

```
df<-data.frame("Sheldon"=c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1),"Leonard"=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1), "Rajesh"=c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0),"Howard"=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1), row.names = c(seq(as.Date("2020-01-01"),by="month",to=as.Date("2020-10-01"))))

        Sheldon  Leonard  Rajesh  Howard
2020/01 0        1        0       1
2020/02 0        1        0       1
2020/03 0        1        0       1
2020/04 0        1        1       1
2020/05 1        1        1       1
2020/06 1        1        1       1
2020/07 1        1        1       1
2020/08 1        0        1       1
2020/09 1        0        0       1
2020/10 1        1        0       1
```

I'd like to calculate for each row *k* with a value of 1 the sum of the *k* rows, such as, as an example:

```
        Sheldon  Leonard  Rajesh  Howard
2020/01 0        1        0       1
2020/02 0        2        0       2
2020/03 0        3        0       3
2020/04 0        4        1       4
2020/05 1        5        2       5
2020/06 2        6        3       6
2020/07 3        7        4       7
2020/08 4        0        5       8
2020/09 5        0        0       9
2020/10 6        0        6       10
```

This I'll have to apply to a big list of dataframes that look like this, so please try to avoid loops.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand the logic of your example. Why is last row of `Leonard` `0` and why is last row of `Rajesh`  `6`

Answer (score 1):

The following shows how to use the `cumsum()` function on a single column.
As the name suggests, `cumsum()` determines the cumulative sum over all rows in your column:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(Sheldon2 = if_else(Sheldon == 1, cumsum(Sheldon), 0))
```

With the `across()` function you can apply statements over multiple columns.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(
    across(everything()   # apply across all columns
          , .fns = ~if_else(.x == 1, cumsum(.x), 0)   # function on generic .x
          ) 
    )
```

This yields:

```
           Sheldon Leonard Rajesh Howard
2020-01-01       0       1      0      1
2020-02-01       0       2      0      2
2020-03-01       0       3      0      3
2020-04-01       0       4      1      4
2020-05-01       1       5      2      5
2020-06-01       2       6      3      6
2020-07-01       3       7      4      7
2020-08-01       4       0      5      8
2020-09-01       5       0      0      9
2020-10-01       6       8      0     10
```

I assume in your example the last entry for Leonard is overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a base R approach:

```
zeros <- which(df==0, arr.ind=TRUE)
df2 <- cumsum(df)
df2[zeros] <- 0
```

In addition to the last row in Leonard being 8, the last row in Rajesh should be 0.